Does an HTML5-plus-CSS3-and-ES15-to-SVG converter exist?
Slightly paraphrased for clarity, "Is it possible to take a screenshot of a web page as an SVG image?" at SuperUser already asks:

I have a webpage which is entirely vector-based (text, icon fonts, SVGs, but no PNGs, JPEGs, or GIFs).
Is there any way to take a vector screenshot of that webpage and save it as a fully-scalable SVG file (so that I can take the screenshot on a normal PC and have it look good on Retina)?
This ought to be possible, but I can't find anything that will do it.
Extra credit: If it has a few bitmap images, I want an SVG with embedded bitmaps.

However, many of its answers, merely due to their age, are of dubious. Additionally, this subdomain is a much better fit for any software recommendation than SU is.
Consequently, what is the best tool for capturing screenshots of entire webpages in vector formats? I ideally want to be able to capture the entire page or merely the visible viewport, and I want to be able to capture it as an SVG.

"no PNGs, JPEGs, or GIFs" and no JavaScript, no animated content and probably no CSS, since CSS is quite a monster

2024 answer: https://superuser.com/a/1826663/105621 2020 answer: https://superuser.com/a/1607301/105621 An answer which will never be out of date: https://superuser.com/a/583254/105621 Have you tried those? Why are they dubios?

@ThomasWeller, your "2024" answer utterly destroyed the formatting of my control sample .HTML file. The next answer is duplicate.

@ThomasWeller, exporting to PDF, without utilizing comparatively complex CLI tooling, tends to produce rasters for a significant amount of originally vectoral elements. Solely GIMP3 and LibreOffice Writer appear to provide the preferences necessary to export a PDF correctly, and even then, neither support converting HTML to PDF. Irrespective, I am thankful for the assistance.

As recommended at SuperUser, the "SVG Screenshots" browser extension does provide this capability, albeit solely in a rudimentary state. In my experience, it does not apply CSS and JS code correctly linked to the HTML file. I know of no alternative.
